# How to "clean" a DC brushed motor : noise on CANbus even without moving!

Tags: noise, emc, can, emi-filtering, brushed-dc-motor

We have very odd problem with a DC brushed geared motor that we are driving with a classical H-bridge chopper (20kHz PWM at the moment). The motor kinda looks like a Mabuchi from an R/C car but with an epicycloidal gearbox in front of it.

We had another motor from another manufacturer that was working perfectly but with this one the CANbus keeps dropping frames as soon as it is even connected with the speed controller. Not even moving! Just connected with no current whatsoever.

We've tried various controllers and also various motors (same model) and the problem doesn't change.

We've also recently seen some problems with low voltage signals picking up noise when it's connected.

The only fix is to use a separate CANbus AND power supply. In all other cases, problems keep on piling up.

We've put different toroidal chokes and went up to dozens of turns into big ones but while that helped, definitely not enough...

Any idea or lead that we could follow?

Thank you all by advance,

Comment: How you run your power & ground lead to the motor can be critical.    Make sure any current flowing through the motor does not also flow along the same copper as the digital stuff as much as possible.  Generally speaking, if the motor and CPU connect at the main power supply and nowhere else that's best.     However, you might try putting a capacitor, say 1-10uF non-polarized, directly across the motor terminal (in addition to your chokes).  In production, we also often place a ceramic cap (0.1uF-ish) from each terminal to the motors metal case. Yes - three capacitors are needed occasionally.

Comment: https://article.murata.com/sites/default/files/static/en-global/images/article/emc/en-20120214-p1_img0002.png       Your choke should be wound as "common mode"... meaning both these chokes are on the same toroid core.

Comment: To add to Kyle B's comments, you may also want to twist the motor wires together, this will keep noise from radiating from them.

Comment: Any chance there's a shunt capacitor between the motor terminals on one motor but not the other?

Comment: Does it have the 3 capacitors on its terminals? Did the original one? (0.1 uF ceramic, in a triangle : one across the terminals, the others from each terminal to a GND point on the case.)

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the feedback.
There is a small PCB on the back of the motor with SMD capacitors on it. They are definitely for RF purposes (as the PCB states : RF something something, I'll have to check).
And no, the original one didn't even have -at least visible- capacitors. It was of much higher quality though : Maxon brand.

Comment: The better motor could have had those caps inside the case, which is the ideal.  Or it could be using (even better) an X2Y cap, also inside the case.

Comment: OK, will try with an X2Y cap.
But what about the fact that it's noisy even without running? The second we connect it, perturbations happen...

Comment: _"the original one ... was ... Maxon brand"_ - exactly which motor was it?

Comment: Have you checked these: [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/276251)

Comment: In addition you could add TVS and EMI filter to the CAN lines. But if you know the source of the noise, always stop it at its source if possible. Motors are notorious for this.